# How to change color of this Donut from codepen?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm stuck on a little problem, I don't know JS at all. I would like to put half of color on the left, the other half on the right, while there is one that: `var colour = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);` which bothers me.

How to add a color for each "piece" of the donut?
I want this color on the left : `#273c4e` and this one on the right : `#b7ce39`

Thank you.

Link of the donut : https://codepen.io/MeredithU/pen/OVMjjK

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm stuck on something, can you help me? (donut from copen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63380162/im-stuck-on-something-can-you-help-me-donut-from-copen)

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
var colour = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);
```

You can change `d3.schemeCategory20` to any of the following: schemeAccent, schemeDark2, schemePastel2, schemeSet2, schemeSet1, schemePastel1, schemeCategory10, schemeSet3, schemePaired, schemeCategory20, schemeCategory20b, schemeCategory20c

Comment: Ok but If i want to add custom color?

Comment: `length = someInteger; colour = d3.scale.linear().domain([1,length]).interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl).range([d3.rgb("#273c4e"), d3.rgb('#b7ce39')]);`